# Attribute to describe about doing something smartly with clear direction

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary, attributive-nouns

When I research about wolves, I found that they have a very interesting attribute: they always do things (hunting, "trekking", caring...) with a well-planned & clear direction/strategy and do smartly. In English, is there any word describe that attribute?
Thanks!

Comment: possibly focus.

Comment: Since this is a single word request it needs a sample sentence (see the Tour).

Answer (score 3):

*Purposeful*, perhaps:

> **purposeful** adjective
>
> showing that you know what you want to do:
>
> *He has a quiet, purposeful air.*

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/purposeful)

Comment: @NigelJ Good point. I should really have posted two answers, since I couldn't decide between them.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "orderly".  A google search provided this definition.

**or·der·ly
/ˈôrdərlē/**

adjective
adjective: orderly

1. *neatly and methodically arranged.*
   "an orderly arrangement of objects"
   synonyms:   neat, tidy, well ordered, in order, trim, in apple-pie order, as neat as a new pin, spick and span, well kept, straight; informal - shipshape (and Bristol fashion)
   "an orderly room"

**antonyms:**   disorderly, untidy, chaotic, messy
(of a person or group) well behaved; disciplined.

**synonyms:**   well behaved, law-abiding, disciplined, peaceful, peaceable, nonviolent, controlled, restrained, civilized, well mannered, polite, courteous, decorous; archaic - ruly as in - "the crowd was quiet and orderly"

**antonyms:**   disorderly, unruly

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like they are **diligent** (adj.) or acting **diligently** (adv.) or acting with due **diligence** (noun). I'll focus on the adjective. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diligent):

> : characterized by steady, earnest, and energetic effort : painstaking

The basic idea is that the effort is well-planned by habit. Someone who is *diligent* is so focused and steady that they are unlikely to miss a detail.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/diligent) specifies *careful* and *serious*:

> careful and serious in your work, or done in a careful and determined way:

Answer (score 0):

There is also *undeviating*:

> **undeviating** adjective
>
> not turning aside or departing from a set direction or intention
>
> *ruthless and undeviating commitment to their cause*

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/undeviating)

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you are looking for is *decisive.*

As per the [dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?ei=UVVIXbWwF5CmUonQl_AH&q=decisive%20meaning&oq=decisive%20meaning&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71l8.876797.876964..877138...0.0..0.210.210.2-1......0....1..gws-wiz.u8A3XQJcAdE&ved=0ahUKEwj1nOS-j-zjAhUQkxQKHQnoBX4Q4dUDCAo&uact=5), decisive is an adjective and here is what it means:

1. Settling an issue; producing a definite result.

**synonyms:**   deciding, conclusive, determining, final, settling, key;

**antonyms:**   insignificant

2. having or showing the ability to make decisions quickly and effectively.

**synonyms:**   resolute, firm, strong-minded, strong-willed, determined;

**antonyms:**   indecisive

---

> Wolves are decisive

because they make a choice and follow through with clear direction to achieve a definite result.

I am not sure about the "smart" part but it is a belief of mine that it takes some good level of smartness to make a decision and effectively follow through it to get the particular result you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I like the adjective "intent" for this because it means both "determined to do something" and also "attentively occupied with".  These two definitions are from Oxford's online dictionary (www.lexico.com).  Or as Collin's online dictionary (www.collinsdictionary.com), puts it: "If someone does something in an intent way, they pay great attention to what they're doing."

Answer (score 0):

Try **[methodical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/methodical)** :

> **methodical** [məˈTHädək(ə)l] ADJECTIVE
>
> done according to a systematic or established form of procedure; (of a person) orderly or systematic in thought or behavior
>
> *synonyms:* orderly · well ordered · well organized · well thought out · planned · well planned · efficient · businesslike · coherent · systematic · scientific · structured · logical

Sample sentence:

> *"Wolves are methodical pack hunters, and their natural coordination, stamina, and tenacity make them dangerous predators in large numbers."*

Answer (score 0):

*focus* seems to me to encompass the purposeful activity you see in the behavior of the wolves, especially the second definition as a verb.

> noun
>   1.
>   the center of interest or activity.
>   "this generation has made the environment a focus of attention"
>   synonyms:   center, focal point, central point, center of attention, hub, pivot, nucleus, heart, cornerstone, linchpin, kingpin, bedrock, basis, anchor, backbone, cynosure
>   "schools are a focus of community life"
>   2.
>   the state or quality of having or producing clear visual definition.
>   "his face is rather out of focus"
>   synonyms:   focal point, point of convergence More
>
> verb
>   1.
>   (of a person or their eyes) adapt to the prevailing level of light and become able to see clearly.
>   "try to focus on a stationary object"
>   2.
>   pay particular attention to.
>   "the study will focus on a number of areas in Wales"

From Google, New Oxford American Dictionary